# How do I make a TextInput editable and focus on it in the same go?

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
    const handleClick = () => {
        setToggleEditable(true);
        textInput.current.focus();
    }
```

A button triggers this when pressed, setting the TextInput with the ref "textInput" to be editable, and then tries to focus on it. However, it never focuses on it the first time the button is pressed. I think that is because the TextInput hasn't finished being set as editalbe, so it can't focus on it. Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by waiting a little (100-150 ms) after button was pressed and then focusing on textinput

```
  focusOn = (ref: TextInput) => {
    setTimeout(() => ref.focus(), 100)
  }
```